# Does this OpenSSL function ever fail?

Tags: c, openssl

I want to use the OpenSSL function `EVP_MD_CTX_new` in my code. The [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_MD_CTX_new.html) for this function states only that it "allocates and returns a digest context". Since this function allocates memory, I am assuming it *can* fail, but the documentation is silent on whether this is true, and what the return value is, in the case of failure.

I am somewhat new at C programming, and to me the interface of this function seems incompletely specified. What is a programmer to do in this case? How should I test for failure? Should I test for `NULL`? If yes, why on earth are they not explicit about it?

Thanks for your thoughts.

*Bonus (more general) question: Needless to say, this particular function (and library) is just one of many similar examples I've encountered. My experience so far is that interfaces for many C functions are incompletely specified in some regard or another. How do more veteran C programmers deal with these situations? Are we expected to rely on convention? Or perhaps dig into the code of the libraries we use to see what the behaviour is?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assume that an function in C which allocates an object and fails returns NULL, in this case it just calls OPENSSL_zalloc. The [manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/OPENSSL_zalloc.html) specifies that OPENSSL_zalloc returns NULL on Error.

They aren't explicit in this, because the assume that everbody knows that a function which creates an object and fails returns NULL. This is a very common convention.

The Implementation in [digest.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/evp/digest.c).

```c
EVP_MD_CTX *EVP_MD_CTX_new(void)
{
    return OPENSSL_zalloc(sizeof(EVP_MD_CTX));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you have any thoughts on my bonus question? I noticed that you did exactly what I mentioned there - relied on convention and looked at the implementation. Is this what you'd think is normally required in the C world?